# How can I use a custom made button class as a paypal buy now button?

Tags: html, button, paypal, customization

This is the current html code to create the image for the paypal button

```
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif"     border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
```

but I want to use a custom button class I've made that looks like this

```
<a class="btn btn-reveal add-top-half" href="http://www.google.com">Buy Now!</a>
```

Is there any way to use the custom button class "btn btn-reveal add-top-half" to direct to the paypal payment page?

Answer (score 1):

Delete the `src` attribute from the original then just add your classes to the original.
Here is how it should look.

```
<input class="btn btn-reveal add-top-half" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
```

Comment: This only partially works. It should create a button but instead it creates a text box that when I hit enter while it is selected it takes me to paypal. I've made this button outside of using it for paypal and it works so I don't think the issue is in the creation of the button but rather how it is implemented.

Comment: <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
                <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
                    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="IM BLOCKING THIS OUT ON PURPOSE">
                        <input class="btn btn-reveal add-top-half" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
                            <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
            </form>